# How to use agSelectCellEditor for dropdown values coming from database in Angular Grid

Tags: typescript, dropdown, angular8, ag-grid-angular

I am using refData and agSelectCellEditor in Angular 8 to show the dropdown value upon editing. I refer to below link to solve my problem:-

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-reference-data/

But dropdown list data is coming from Database via HTTP GET query. I am using "cellEditorParams" in agGrid which contain method "extractValues()" as you can see below. The problem is that the method runs before the data came from Database and this results to blank data. How to resolve the issue?

Ideally dropdown should contain values as "Yes/No". When I am declaring "objCategoryMappings" at the top with static list then it is working fine. Is there any limitation like "refData" dont work with dynamic list from database? If so then what is the alternative?

[image]

Please refer the code below. For simplicity I have set "Yes/No" statically inside subscribe method. In real scenario I would be using "objCategoryMappings" to store values from database.

**HTML**

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-balham" [gridOptions]="categoryGridOptions"
            [rowData]="categoryRowData" [columnDefs]="categoryColDef"  
            (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
        </ag-grid-angular>
```

**TS File**

```
export class CategoryComponent{
  categoryRowData: any[]; 
  objCategoryMappings = {};

  constructor() {
        this.getAllCategories();                  
  } 

  getAllCategories()
    {            
        this.categoryCommonService.getEntityData('getallcatgories')
            .subscribe((rowData) => {                 
                this.categoryRowData = rowData;               
                this.objCategoryMappings["f"] = "No";
                this.objCategoryMappings["t"] = "Yes";                
            },
                (error) => { alert(error) });       
    }          

  categoryColDef = [
       {
            headerName: 'Category Name', field: 'CategoryName',                        
            cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor',
            cellEditorParams: {
                maxLength: '50',
                cols: '20',
                rows: '1'
            }
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Is Subcategory', field: 'IsSubcategory', //Values coming from db as "f" and "t"             
            cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
            cellEditorParams: {
                values: this.extractValues(this.objCategoryMappings),                                
            },                                                      
            refData: this.objCategoryMappings,            
        }];

    extractValues(mappings) {
        return Object.keys(mappings);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why are you building the objCategoryMappings object after getting the grid row data ? as I see  it's static and you don't need the api response to build it.

If you want to keep this logic then even the columns definition should done after the api response because it needs the objCategoryMappings data which is currently undefined at definition time  :

```
export class CategoryComponent{
  categoryRowData: any[]; 
  objCategoryMappings = {};
  categoryColDef ;

  constructor() {
        this.getAllCategories();                  
  } 

 getAllCategories()
    {            
        this.categoryCommonService.getEntityData('getallcatgories')
            .subscribe((rowData) => {                 
                this.categoryRowData = rowData;               
                this.objCategoryMappings["f"] = "No";
                this.objCategoryMappings["t"] = "Yes";    
                this.createColumnsDefinition() ;            
            },
                (error) => { alert(error) });       
    }          

createColumnsDefinition(){
     this.categoryColDef = [
       {
            headerName: 'Category Name', field: 'CategoryName',                        
            cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor',
            cellEditorParams: {
                maxLength: '50',
                cols: '20',
                rows: '1'
            }
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Is Subcategory', field: 'IsSubcategory', //Values coming from db as "f" and "t"             
            cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
            cellEditorParams: {
                values: this.extractValues(this.objCategoryMappings),                                
            },                                                      
            refData: this.objCategoryMappings,            
        }];

...
}
```

and inside your html you need to wait for data receiving before rendering the grid as **c_ogoo** said :

```
<ag-grid-angular
  *ngIf="categoryColDef" 
  class="ag-theme-balham" 
  [gridOptions]="categoryGridOptions"
  [rowData]="categoryRowData" 
  [columnDefs]="categoryColDef"  
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: You are Awesome Z. Your idea of calling Column definition after database call worked like a charm for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can control when the data is required by `ag-grid` by using the `ngIf` directive.

```html
<ag-grid-angular
  *ngIf="categoryRowData" 
  class="ag-theme-balham" 
  [gridOptions]="categoryGridOptions"
  [rowData]="categoryRowData" 
  [columnDefs]="categoryColDef"  
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

This will delay the render of the `ag-grid` component until the data is available

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I call columnDefinition after Database call then it worked for me. In this case *ngIf is not needed. But then also thanks for suggesting this.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Unlike the best answer, you don't need to create categoryColDef when data is receiving to the application. You can create it earlier, and only make the change to the objCategoryMappings. What this implementation does is to remove existing elements from objCategoryMappings whenever new data is receiving to the application from the database or somewhere. Of course you can just add new data too with push() method, but the problem is whenever new data receives to the application, the old elements in the array are not removed; hence new data is added to array that already has old data. I have experienced this with Firebase. I think this solution makes it easy to manage the codes.

```
objCategoryMappings = [];

this.categoryCommonService.getEntityData('getallcatgories')
            .subscribe((rowData) => {                 
                this.objCategoryMappings.length = 0;           
                this.objCategoryMappings.push(...rowData);             
            });
            
          
 cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams: { values: objCategoryMappings}
```

---

Another solution. In this solution, it assumes data of both rowData, and objCategoryMappings are in the same location, and therefore you can compare the elements of same locations to see whether there is any new change. if there was, then make the change in the objCategoryMappings instead of replacing all the values. This can be a very efficient solution. *(I didn't test this solution unlike the first one)*

```
objCategoryMappings = [];

this.categoryCommonService.getEntityData('getallcatgories')
  .subscribe((rowData) => {
    this.assign(rowData);           
});


function assign(rowData){
    for(var i=0; i<rowData.length; i++) {
     if (rowData[i] != objCategoryMappings[i]) {
        objCategoryMappings[i] = rowData[i];
     }
  }
}


cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams: { values: objCategoryMappings}
```

[You can set the length property to truncate an array at any time.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)